# MIPS using jal inside a function

Tags: assembly, mips

I am using mips and i have to call a function inside a function like this.

```
main() {
    func1();
}
func1(){ 
    func2(); 
}
func2(){}
```

and I tried this:

```
.data

str1: .asciiz "Başlıyo\n"   
str2: .asciiz "Bitti\n"
str3: .asciiz "Loopta\n"
str4: .asciiz "funct1\n"
str5: .asciiz "funct2\n"

.text
.globl main
main:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str1
    syscall

    jal func1
    jal func2
    j exit

func1:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str4
    syscall

    jal func2

    jr $ra

func2:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str5
    syscall

    jr $ra;

exit :

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str2
    syscall
```

I'm using `QtSpim` in `Ubuntu` and it doesn't give error but can't see the output

> `str2"Bitti"`

Comment: You realize that everytime you use `jal` the `$ra` register gets updated? So if function A calls function B, then A must save `$ra` somewhere (e.g. on the stack) to be able to return to whoever called A.

Comment: if stack and push $ra can i be free

Comment: I'm not sure what _"can i be free"_ means. Just try it and see what happens.